# URLs amigables, eliminar/sustituir partes de una URL .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

Tengo esta url para acceder a un estudio dentro de la web:

```
http://miweb.com/index.php?option=com_component&view=estudio&factura=1&id=25977&token=8f8c54a3ce165332fd59f17
```

Quiero que una URL similar la siguiente, redireccione a la anterior

```
http://miweb.com/estudio&factura=1&id=25977&token=8f8c54a3ce165332fd59f17
```

Es decir, que se sustituya una parte de la URL, pero mantenga el resto de parámetros.

Hasta el momento, he editado **mod_rewrite** del archivo .htaccess y he conseguido que me sustituya strings (por ejemplo `com_component`), pero no la cadena `index.php?option=com_component&view=estudio`. Esto me da error, ¿será por los `?&=`?

```
RewriteEngine On
Rewritebase /

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)com_component(.*) [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) $1?%1nuevostring%2 [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

¿Cómo puedo sustituir toda la línea `index.php?option=com_component&view=estudio` por una palabra (ej. "estudio")?

Edito:

¿Es posible que en la URL se sirva a la URL con todos los parámetros, pero que no aparezca la parte de `index.php?option=com_component&view=estudio`? No quiero que el usuario vea el nombre de option y view, pero en cambio son parámetros que me hacen falta para que funcione la URL

Comment: No termino de entender. Para empezar, `/estudio&factura=1&...` es inválida. El primer caracter del parámetro es siempre un `?`... Además, ¿estás buscando una redirección o una reescritura? ¿estás buscando que cambie la URL, o que cuando se ingrese a `/estudio` en realidad esté sirviendo el index.php con estos 2 parámetros: `view=estudio&option=com_component`?

Comment: Si no se entendió mi comentario anterior, probá agregando esta regla al final: `RewriteRule ^estudio$ index.php?option=com_component&view=estudio [NC,QSA,L]` y fijate si es lo que estás buscando.

Comment: He editado con un comentario adicional. Estoy un poco verde en esto de las redirecciones, no sé si lo que propongo es posible y se entiende... Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: creo que la respuesta es lo que te comenté ayer... voy a publicarlo como respuesta así vemos si es lo que estás buscando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes que nada, fijate que tenés un error en la URL. Los parámetros siempre empiezan con `?` y se separan con `&`. La URL a la que va a acceder el usuario final va a ser:

```
http://miweb.com/estudio?factura=1&id=25977&token=8f8c54a3ce165332fd59f17
```

Lo que estás buscando es una **reescritura** (no redirección), que implica tomar una URL y servir un recurso diferente (reescrito), pero sin modificar la URL del cliente (sin redireccionar), de forma transparente para éste.

O sea, tendríamos la redirección que ya está en tus reglas para modificar un parámetro, y le agregaríamos esta reescritura:

```py
RewriteEngine On
Rewritebase /

# Redireccionar para eliminar el parámetro de la URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*[&?]option=)com_component((?:[&?]|$).*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) $1?%1com_newname%2 [R=302,L]

# Reescritura de /estudio  a  index.php?option=com_component&view=estudio
RewriteRule ^estudio$ index.php?option=com_component&view=estudio [NC,QSA,L]
```

Así, cuando el cliente accede a:

```
http://miweb.com/estudio?factura=1&id=25977&token=8f8c54a3ce165332fd59f17
```

Apache le sirve esta URL (de forma transparente):

```
http://miweb.com/index.php?option=com_component&view=estudio&factura=1&id=25977&token=8f8c54a3ce165332fd59f17
```